# Change video source on Samsung Syncmaster 2233SW without OSD?

Tags: display

I have a samsung syncmaster 2233SW which i bought second hand a few years back. The monitor was damaged so i took it to a repair shop which disabled the buttons on the side. Now that shop's closed so i can't consult them anymore.

Is there any way for me to change the source of the content from VGA to DVI without OSD? I already tried magictune.

Comment: Have you disconnected the VGA cable?  Is the cable you have [DVI-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) or DVI-I (i.e. not DVI-A).  Is your graphics card output enabled and set to 1920x1080?  If you've not seen the manual then it is on the [samsung site](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/200905/20090526190001531/BN59-00950A-02Eng.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

By default the fourth button from the top on the right-hand edge (the "Customize" button) will change between Analog and Digital via a short single press (unless it's been customised to do something else!)  There is a minor lag - be patient if you don't get an instant change.  Five seconds should be plenty.